# Windows 11 23H2: Dual touch monitors issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11-v23h2

Good morning

I'm currently unable to get two touch screens to work simultaneously with Windows 11 23H2.

The touch works well on each screen when plugged in individually.

When I plug in both, the touch of one screen applies to the other screen and the touch of this other screen does not work at all.

While looking for information, I came across the calibration of this type of screen via the "tablet pc settings" in the control panel but it's a failure

When I launch the tool with the calibration, I got a white screen with a message asking to me to touch the screen where appears the message. It works using the first touch screen.

Then, the same message appears on the second screen but the touch does not work at all on this second screen and I'm not able to complete the calibration, I need to press escape to exit the tool, since I cannot touch the second screen.

Doing this calibration solves the first issue which was that the touch of one screen controls the second screen.

Has anyone ever encountered this type of problem and has a magic fix?

Thank you